# Translate literal words for the \convertnumber command

Tags: context, convert, translate

I need to get a verbal form of simple numbers

```
\mainlanguage[english] % english spanish - works
                       % danish dutch - doesn't work
\setupbodyfont[dejavu]


\starttext

    The current head label language = \headlanguage

    \convertnumber{Words}{1}

    \convertnumber{Words}{25}

\stoptext
```

I've figured out that words for English and Spanish are defined in the core-con.lua file and they work well in a ConTeXt file through language set upping

However, how can literal words be translated/set up for other languages? Is it possible without editing core-con.lua?

Comment: If you know what to add for those languages, you can add it to the file and send it to Hans. He will diff and check it is OK, and then you have contributed. I can imagine Danish being a bit difficult to get right.